# What is the meaning of "I am glossing over a significant amount of spherical myalgia"?

Tags: meaning, euphemism

Today I encountered a saying where I think the last part has been replaced with a euphemism.

> [I am glossing over a significant amount of spherical myalgia.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27443387/efficient-algorithm-to-search-a-buffer-for-any-string-from-a-list#comment43331246_27443387)

I could make out the meaning from the context. The meaning is "I am skipping a lot of gritty detail".

What is the original saying (if there is one)?

Comment: [Myalgia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myalgia) = muscle pain. These things don't have a shape.

Comment: Could "spherical myalgia" mean headache? Heads are round (sort of)

Comment: Oh, _that_ muscle. Interesting idea...

Comment: A rougher expression would've been "a significant amount of gluteal myalgia".

Comment: @CopperKettle Nice one, too.

Comment: @CopperKettle True, but that would shift the meaning from necessary pain to unnecessary pain. But it's a good one!

Comment: Google Books contains not a single instance of the collocation ["spherical myalgia"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22spherical+myalgia%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl). Perhaps the author is one of those (relatively rare) people who uses ***ballsache*** (pain in the testicles) to mean ***hassle***. I don't know what *reason* to cite, but I don't think this question is a good fit to a *learners* website. It's effectively not even "English".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just my humorous way of describing ball ache. Spherical=ball shaped, myalgia=medical term for pain/ache.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a doctor so I can think of this usage. And trust me, we as students used to use a lot of such phrases just to have fun using medical jargon! This included, *that is beyond your gray matter- beyond your thinking*, *paralyzed orbicularis oris -someone who never smiles!* and a lot more. Ah, I just had nostalgia!

Okay, to begin with...

*[myalgia](http://www.merriam-webster.com/medlineplus/myalgia)* is pain in one or more muscle but here, in this context the *pain* is important and not the muscle because it's about the author's brain. The human brain is not required to 'move' and thus, our [*brain* does not contain any muscle](http://www.enotes.com/homework-help/how-many-muscles-brain-150617).

Now back to the sarcastic comment in which the author has played a pun. As you said that the intention is to *'I am skipping a lot of [gritty](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/gritty) detail'* which means you don't want to bother your *brain* much about it though you know the truth.

The word *spherical* is used for the brain. We doctors use *[spheres](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cerebral_hemisphere)* to refer to the human brain.

So, to rephrase and reverse a 'pun' played on it, the sentence means though the things are right, the author simply wants to save his/er brain from pain (or bothering).